# How to format DATETIME type data from "2018-12-14T14:16:58.037967" to "2018-12-14 14:16:58.037967" with Groovy?

Tags: datetime, groovy

How to format `DATETIME` type data from `2018-12-14 14:16:58.037967` to `2018-12-14T14:16:58.037967` with Groovy?

*Program:*

```java
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def DB_formattime = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-05-18 20:54:04.638314", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.n"))

print DB_formattime
```

*Error:*

```
Caught: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-05-18 20:54:04.638314' could not be parsed at index 10
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-05-18 20:54:04.638314' could not be parsed at index 10
    at java_time_LocalDateTime$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    at test.run(test.groovy:4)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

ihmo the simplest way here just to replace space with 'T' char...

```
"2018-12-14 14:16:58.037967".tr(' ','T')
```

however if you'd like to parse and format the date:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime 
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def DB_formattime = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-05-18 20:54:04.638314", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.n"))
DB_formattime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.n"))
```